# JBoss 5.1.0. GA shutdown

Tags: performance, jboss5.x, shutdown, message-driven-bean

On a 5.1.0GA. server,at shutdown :

Normally, when I call shutdown on the jboss, I would expect that the following happens:

1. all MDBs do stop processing any further JMS
2. all (Quartz) jobs are closing down
3. jboss is shutting down itself

However, it seems that the MDBs closing is not happening – at least this is not the first task, but the MDBs do still process

messages though jboss did already start to close EJB components (which is actually bad) and thus the total shutdown takes really a while.There are several exceptions(NameNotFound) raised when lookup is made for objects that have been unbound from the JNDI tree.

Can I force somehow the order in which components are stopped , and stop MDB's first?

Comment: I'd like to know too. Did you ever come around to solve this?

Comment: Same problem here (though 6.0M1, which is almost the same in many aspects). Workaround: Use the JMX console to stop delivery to each of the MDBs. Wait for them to finish their work and shutdown JBoss afterwards.